# Atom errors pane is not making sense

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

What are the three panes about line 103 trying to tell me? It looks like a bug to me, because line 103 does not contain the text indicated. The letters "seem" to be letters I typed while coding, in reverse order.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should just log bugs on their GitHub site? https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Never sure where it gets the right eyeballs. I've gotten a lot of good help here on typescript and atom. But I will post it there too. Thanks.

Comment: Will need more context than is present in the question. Feel free to log a bug

Comment: Ok @basarat. Never sure if its a bug in the typescript package or atom or my own brain. In this case, what are those three panes "supposed" to be displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, what are those three panes "supposed" to be displaying

Verbose versions : "errors in open typescript files" "last build output errors" "find references results"